# CakePHP 3: Truncate a table

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

How can I truncate a table with CakePHP 3.x

I get the truncate query by this:

```
$this->Coupons->schema()->truncateSql($this->Coupons->connection());
```

but what is the best practice to execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code working well, thanks to [@ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) for his comment that helped the answer to be better.

```
    //In Coupons Controller
    $this->Coupons->connection()->transactional(function ($conn) {
        $sqls = $this->Coupons->schema()->truncateSql($this->Coupons->connection());
        foreach ($sqls as $sql) {
            $this->Coupons->connection()->execute($sql)->execute();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You shoud reuse `$this->Coupons->connection()`, also use `foreach` to iterate over and execute _all_ possible SQL statements returned by `truncateSql()`, and finally wrap this in a [**transaction**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions). Other than that, that's generally how it's done, there are no other methods supplied by the framework for truncating tables.

Answer (score 2):

In **CakePHP4** you can use the following code to truncate a table:

```
$table = $this->Coupons;
$sqls = $table->getSchema()->truncateSql($table->getConnection());
foreach ($sqls as $sql) {
  $table->getConnection()->execute($sql)->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested following and it's worked:

```php
  $connection = $this->Coupons->getConnection();
  $connection->query('TRUNCATE coupons');
```

Reference: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#executing-queries

Read more here: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions